# EMPTY dropdown content box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want a button that when clicked a dropbown box appears with a little triangle on top connecting it to the button (similar to what a lot of the Google UI looks like). This is very similar to dropdown menu in jQuery ui or popover in bootstrap. However, I want the box to essentially be an empty div.

The closest I have found is the one that foundation has (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html) but I don't understand their code enough to fully edit it the way I want (also I don't full understand how to use compass with it in order to do things like change the min-width or change the triangle color - I assume the triangle is another div behind the main box with a radius that gives it a triangle?). I also plan on using php/ajax inside the box so I am worried about compatibility with Foundation.

So the question is does anyone know of anyway to do this with JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or are you looking for a solution without bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of jQuery's `.hide()`, `.show()`, and `.toggle()` for this kind of effect.  Then it's just a matter of using CSS to get it to look how you want.

Example: (pulled HTML from your link)

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="drop1-link">Has Dropdown</a>
    <ul id="drop1">
        <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#" id="drop2-link">Has Content Dropdown</a>
    <div id="drop2">
        <p>Some text that people will think is awesome! Some text that people will think is awesome! Some text that people will think is awesome!</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#drop1").hide();
        $("#drop2").hide();
    });

    $("#drop1-link").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#drop1").toggle();
    });

    $("#drop2-link").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#drop2").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3b3xz/

Comment: Thank you very much for answering! Two more questions (and again sorry if these are really basic!): (1) How do use CSS  so that the drop down positioning is always relative to the button (or in your example the link)? (2) how do I have it so that if you click anywhere else on the screen, the box (the div) hides. THANKS AGAIN!!

Comment: I don't know if I am supposed to @Greg you for you to see that I sent a comment. Sorry if this is unnecessary. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, sorry. I did see the earlier comment but I haven't been at a computer to give a proper response (won't have anything but my phone all weekend).  There are lots of tutorials around for positioning elements with CSS, I know you can figure it out :). As far as the hide on clicking anywhere else, you'll need to do something like `$(document).click(function(){$('#drop1 #drop2').hide(); });` ... Hopefully that points you in the right direction :)